# Hibernate concurrent modification in collection

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa

Does anyone has experiences about the following situation?

Say, I have an entity A with a collection in it. This collection contains some entities of type B (@OneToMany). Two users load entity A and change entity B, but the first user change entity B on index 1 and the second user change entity B on index 2.

Will this result into problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different `B` entities will be saved independently from each other. So there will be no overwriting, deadlocks, etc., if you mean that.

However, if the logic in your application is such that changes on the two are logically dependent on each other, then that will result in an inconsistent state. For example, let's say that only one of `B`s in the collection can be in status `Active`. Obviously, the possibility to change both to be `Active` is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. No, there is no logical dependency between the B's.